# Lift (Scala) nested snippets (multiple items per day)

Tags: scala, lift

Trying to get started with Scala by playing around with the Lift framework and I'm having trouble creating what I imagined would be typify a common scenario: I have a list of days and for each day a list of items for that day (nested lists).

My thought was to take this approach:

```
<div class="lift:DaySnippet">
    <h1 class="day">Name of Day</h1>
    <ul class="day-items">
        <!-- wanted to have a separate snippet but haven't made it work -->
        <!-- <li class="lift:DayItemSnippet">Item content</li> -->
        <li class="item">
            <span class="name">Name</span>
            <span class="desc">Description</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Originally I wasn't going to have the inner snippet but thought that made sense.

So I can define a snippet like this:

```
class DaySnippet {
    // Ignoring that this is a stupid way to define the data
    val days = ("Monday", ("Item 1", "Item 1 Description") :: Nil) ::
        ("Tuesday", ("Item 2", "Item 2 Description") ::
            ("Item 3", "Item 3 Description") :: Nil) :: Nil;

    def render = {
        // EDIT: Original code was broken, this is what I was trying to show

        "* *" #> days.map { case (day, items) => ".day *" #> day }
    }
}
```

At any rate, I'm looking for some documents or examples of either nesting snippets and/or how to iterate over nested collections and use CssSels to modify the whole NodeSeq as we go.

I'd be happy to add any additional information that might clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up with some code to do what I wanted, but I'm not sure it's optimal so suggestions are welcome:

```
class DaySnippet {
    // Ignoring that this is a stupid way to define the data
    val days = ("Monday", ("Item 1", "Item 1 Description") :: Nil) ::
        ("Tuesday", ("Item 2", "Item 2 Description") ::
            ("Item 3", "Item 3 Description") :: Nil) :: Nil;

    def render = {
        "* *" #> days.map { case (day, items) =>
            ".day *" #> day & ".item *" #> item.map {
                case (name, desc) =>
                    ".name *" #> name * ".desc *" #> desc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here good [discussion](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/can-I-do-something-like-this-with-nested-snippets-td1968771.html), using S.attr to get index of nested snippet is described.

Comment: I actually came across this discussion, but I wanted to use CssSel instead of bind.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using S.attr in this case.  The original poster's code is the correct approach.